# list of apt-get packages for upgrade

Tags: upgrade, aptitude

I have a 9.10 machine used for development by one of my colleagues. A new team member has joined us, and he wants to have the same development environment on his 10.04 machine as the one used on the 9.10 one.

I've done some searching and tried using:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

And:

```
aptitude search '~i!~E' | grep -v "i A" | cut -d " " -f 4
```

To get a list of packages I want installed on the 9.10 machine.

The problem is that trying to install the humongous list of packages on the 10.04 machine causes severe dependency problems, and `aptitude` nearly refuses to install them.

Is there a way to get only the distribution-independent packages from the 9.10 machine, i.e. only the packages that will be installed on the 10.04 without problems?

Any ideas?

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the intention is to maintain compatibility, the answer is "probably not". As a simple example, `libc` differs enough between the distributions to make the operating and development environments not behave as desired.

You have a social engineering problem which can be solved with a brick (although a rubber hose leaves less marks): smack the guy who won't upgrade or downgrade as the project requires. You could also move build and test off to a different machine of the appropriate revision and let the engineers use CP/M with WordStar on their desks if they want, but this approach is less fun.

Finally, you could get Mr. 10.04 to set up a cross-compilation environment with a 9.10 target, but it would be really hard to prove that it is correct.

Comment: Wow, all hell broke loose :-) The old guy is no more, the new guy knows very little about Ubuntu. I guess He'll just install his system one package at a time.